# Android MediaPlayer addTimedTextSource not notifying when caption 'ends', only when a caption 'starts'

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, srt, video-subtitles

I have a MediaPlayer setup and I'm loading in a .srt file from my Raw Resources, loading it in via addTimedTextSource and assigning a OnTimedTextListener.

This all seems to be working, the OnTimedTextListener onTimedText events fire.

However I only get events when a caption 'starts' and don't get any event when the caption 'ends' for me to clear the subtitles.

Here's an example .srt file...

```
1
00:00:01,100 --> 00:00:04,100
This is a test subtitle.

2
00:00:06,100 --> 00:00:08,100
This is another subtitle.
```

I get events at 1.100s and 6.100s of the new text, but I need an event at 4.100s to tell me to hide the first subtitle...this isn't happening. I would expect to get an event at 4.100s with Text being 'null' or empty string.

Any thoughts why?

For now I'm having to do a work around with a 'clear' caption I can intercept and hide the subtitles like this...

```
1
00:00:01,100 --> 00:00:04,100
This is a test subtitle.

2
00:00:04,100 --> 00:00:06,100
!!!CLEAR!!!

3
00:00:06,100 --> 00:00:08,100
This is another subtitle.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?